# check that the data exists before sending it to wpdb

Tags: wpdb, conditional-tags

When I send data to wpdb from form I can have some empty fields.
How can I add conditions to array of data inside array or before insert wpdb to send only filled fields ?

The fields concerned (for example $serializedpaisol has no value(empty)) have already be checked to know if values exist, but the wpdb->insert find always this data name but is empty:

```
if(isset($paisol)){ 
    $serializedpaisol = maybe_serialize($paisol);
}
$data = array(
        'name' => $_POST['aacl_title'],
        'nicname' => $Acronyme,
        'img' => $idImage,
        'info' => $_POST['aac_description'],
        'resume' => $_POST['aac_resume'],
        'statut' => $serializedcp,
        'mgmt_act' => 1,
        'website' => $serializedurllink,
        'payment_solutions' => $serializedpaisol,
        'mail'=> $mail,
        'tel'=> $tel,
        'location'=> $serializedloc,
        'date'=> $timeday
    );
    $format = array('%d','%s','%s','%d','%s','%s','%s','%d','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s');
    $table = $wpdb->prefix.'table_data';
    $wpdb->insert($table,$data,$format);
```

When I send form I get  "Notice: Undefined variable: serializedpaisol"

I don't understand well wpdb::prepare , does it check the existence of data value before to send to database ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi the error you are getting  for `$serializedpaisol` variable  because  it is not define in function  scope.

the variable you define in specific scope can not access out form its scope;

eg.

```
{
//example scope
$var=10;
}
echo $var; // you will get undefined error.
```

**how you can fixed it?**

**Solution**

```
// first define variable in function  scope

$serializedpaisol ="";

if(isset($paisol)){ 
    $serializedpaisol = maybe_serialize($paisol);
}
echo $serializedpaisol; // now you will not get any error.
```

hope you understand  the point.

Thanks